# ios InfoPlist.strings translations doesn't work but all other i18n files work fine

Tags: ios, xcode, internationalization

I'm currently experiencing an issue where translations in the `InfoPlist.strings` file are completely ignored by the Simulator but at the same time it picks up on all other i18n related files which work fine and the "error" only occurs when the app asks for a given permission from the user.

The following keys are being translated:

`NSCameraUsageDescription`
`NSContactsUsageDescription`
`NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`
`NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`
`NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription`

But the value that is always returned is that of the default `InfoPlist.strings`.

I've verified that the files are properly installed, Xcode isn't detecting any problems with them and shows all the available localizations for the app.

Has anyone had this happen before?

Currently happening with `Xcode 8.2.1` on all supported iOS versions.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else running into this sort of issue, the reason why the UI Notifications weren't being translated is because the simulator REQUIRES for the OS language to be set to the given location.

This means that to properly test that the application is being internationalized, setting the schema to use the given language isn't enough if you're internationalizing say the Notification Permissions text, you must go to Settings > General > Language & Region > iPhone language and set the language to test, only them will you be able to test OS level translations.

Hopes this helps someone.